# Load data on visibility LongListSelector

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I've noticed on certain list controls in WP7 that the lists will load data as the user scrolls to it. I don't know which control this is or if it's just a visual thing, but I'm curious if the data is actually loaded at the item is made visible.

I'm using a longlistselector with a lot of items in it, and if there is a way to selectively load the data in real time, I'd prefer that. Some examples I've seen are twitter and Zune Marketplace lists. Are these Pivots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UX virtualization and data virtualization are 2 different things. The first sounds like what you are talking about and is implemented by default when you bind data to a ListBox.

UX virtualization is discussed [here](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=338)

Data virtualization occurs when data is lazy loaded as required and is discussed [here](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=344).

The LongListSelector is an advanced ListBox so supports UX virtualization. It also supports data virtualization. An article discusses them both [here](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part2-data-binding-scenarios).

Comment: I'm going to try these, but I have had problems getting all the virutualization stuff to work with LongListSelector. Deferred Scrolling isn't an option. Also, isVirtualized causes a compile time error. The only option that seems to work is setting the virtualization to recycling.

Comment: Here's my problem, quote "When using data binding’s “Grouping” feature, there is no support for UI virtualization." from one of the links you gave me. It's a double edged sword i guess. If i use sorting and grouping, it helps the user get what they want, but if i use it, the list might act poorly.